# Kubernetes - How ingress routing works

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I saw some example where the Kubernetes cluster is installed with ingress controller and then the ingress class is added with annotations and host as below.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
 annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx

spec:
 rules:
   - host: testsvc.k8s.privatecloud.com
     http:
```

I am not sure which service is installed and which IP is configured with the DNS **"k8s.privatecloud.com"** so as to route requests?
How the DNS routing **"k8s.privatecloud.com"** routes requests to Kubernetes cluster? How the ingress to kubernetes bridging works?

Also, There could be many services configured with the hosts rule like,

```
testsvc.k8s.privatecloud.com
testsvc1.k8s.privatecloud.com
testsvc2.k8s.privatecloud.com
```

How the subdomain routing works here when we hit the service testsvc.k8s.privatecloud.com or testsvc1.k8s.privatecloud.com ...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DNS for all the hostnames in your given example (e.g. `testsvc.k8s.privatecloud.com`) would point to the machine or load-balancer through which traffic will reach the Ingress controller's nginx, as is described in [the kuberetes Ingress documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)

Subdomain routing is traditionally done via "virtual-hosting", sometimes called "v-host-ing", and the nginx ingress uses the HTTP `Host:` header to know which backend service should receive that traffic. Some Ingress controllers are able to use SNI for that same trick over https.

Comment: I am using a private cloud formed with few linux VM's. So, Do i need to have a network load balancer with DNS name (k8s.privatecloud.com) which will route requests to ingress controllers in Kubernetes and the ingress will use the subdomain routing for the corresponding service?

Comment: Well, it depends on how bytes arrive from the Internet into your few linux VMs; if you are able to expose just one (or two) ports from the VMs to the Internet, then no network load balancer required, because that's what nginx is doing for you. If there are more layers between the Internet and your cluster's Nodes, then yes, a separate mechanism is required to get the bytes down to the nginx's ports in the cluster.

Comment: as for the DNS names, that depends on whether you want `k8s.privatecloud.com` to _also_ be managed by your Ingress, in which case yes, both `k8s.privatecloud.com` and `*.k8s.privatecloud.com` should point to the same mechanism that gets Internet traffic to those nginx ports on your Nodes

Comment: After sending internet traffic to nginx( all *.k8s.privatecloud.com to nginx), How does it routes requests to the corresponding services in Kubernetes cluster? How does that bridging works? nginx to kubernets cluster. Where do we configure this?

Comment: Please read the Ingress documentation, these questions cannot possibly be answered in a 600 character comment box

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Matthew L Daniel answer.
The kubernetes Ingress works as a proxy between external network and your cluster. The behavior of the ingress is explained in the [object ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/). For example:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: foo.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /foo
        backend:
          serviceName: s1
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /bar
        backend:
          serviceName: s2
          servicePort: 80
```

Above it`s explained how to route traffic between 2 backends s1 and s2. Ingress does not hold any information about services except its name and port, every time it needs more details it would need to be requested from the api-server.